# Android stop mediaplayer when preparingAsunc

Tags: java, android

How can I stop media player during loading when I'm using mediaplayer.prepareAsunc(), (after setting path of radiostream).. when I'm finishing activity, it's start playing, after loaded.. how can I stop it during loading? without System.exit(0) method?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
```